# R - instead of plotting, just show the table

Tags: r, plotly, shinydashboard

this is my R code:

```
output$heatmap_viewed_ads <- renderPlotly({
  plot_ly(  x = c(1,2,3,4,5), y = casted_viewed_ads$FEED, z = as.matrix(casted_viewed_ads[2:15]), type = "heatmap",colors = "Greens"  )%>%
  layout(title =  "#Views", xaxis=list(title="Position of Display"))})
```

I am plotting right here this data. I do now want to just show the matrix that is generated by

```
as.matrix(casted_viewed_ads[2:15])
```

Can someone help me please? I'm new to R. I'm using Shiny and Plotly.

Thanks!

Comment: you don't need plotly for showing a table - you can simply use `DT::renderDataTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `renderTable` to display your matrix in the Shiny app.

**Server**

```
output$matrix <- renderTable({

yourmatrix <- as.matrix(casted_viewed_ads[2:15])

yourmatrix 

})
```

**UI**

```
mainPanel(
plotOutput("heatmap_viewed_ads"), #you can eliminate this line if you just want to show the table
tableOutput("matrix")
)
```

Comment: @JohnnyBanana Let me know if it works, I couldn't try since I don't have the data.

Comment: I had to change the UI part (of course), since ours looks a bit different. But seems to work fine. Thanks!